# Grouping table cells (in columns) to be selected by Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table

**What I am trying to achieve**
I am generating part of the calendar depending on the date given by the user. The thing is i generate it the way, it allows user to put some info into it (like school schedule, day schedule).
Now i want to be able to select all cells, withing 1 day (Monday for example), within 1 date (6th january).

**Whats the problem?**
As they are cells in table, they are generated by rows (1st row of Monday, 2nd row of Monday etc) and i haven't found any good way to select a range of cells in column.

**What have I tried so far?**
Well, I was thinking of giving `name` attribute to every cell in the column, with the date, so I could select them all with `getElementsByName()`, but then I would also need to distinguish each of the cell, so I could pick one from the group. But I ran out of ideas, what attribute to use. I got name used, I will probably use class to style it, and also ID NEED to be Unique, so I can't use it, as every date would have 1-8 IDs.

```
<td class="pion" rowspan="8">Monday</td><td class="szerokie">1</td>        
<td name=30.9.2013></td><td name=7.10.2013></td><td name=14.10.2013></td>
<td name=21.10.2013></td><td name=28.10.2013></td><td name=4.11.2013></td>
<td name=11.11.2013></td><td name=18.11.2013></td><td name=25.11.2013></td>
<td name=2.12.2013></td><td name=9.12.2013></td><td name=16.12.2013></td>
<td name=23.12.2013></td><td name=30.12.2013></td><td name=6.1.2014></td>
<td name=13.1.2014></td><td name=20.1.2014></td><td name=27.1.2014></td>
```

Thats code of the **Mondays 1st ROW only**. As you can see, every column got other date in the name, but now i need an idea, how to differ them, from next row (which looks almost the same, except first column after Monday, got number 2 (`<td class="szerokie">2</td>`) .

Whole table in here: http://jsfiddle.net/ptUTm/2/

Of course, completely new idea, how to group them, and then get only 1 wanted from group is welcome too. I do not "require" code, only ideas are also fine!

Comment: Why not use a class? Elements can have multiple classes.  Perhaps chooses a class like table1_col1.  You can pretty easily get elements by class name.  Note that programming a nice interactive table from scratch with a modern-looking ui, selectable columns, etc might be a big project--you might want to find a library.  There's a jQuery one out there (Datatables).  Alternatively, there are many calendar libraries.

Comment: as @AlexMA suggested, I suggest as well to use jQuery: **:first** and **n-th** selectors would come in very handy in this situation

Comment: Also, you could walk the DOM manually or abstractly with jQuery.  That would be another way of finding all of the cells in your column.  A bit trickier, but possibly better in the long run.

Comment: @Kedor why cant you use custom attributes for each cell and use jQuery to select the cells whichmeet ur criteria? For example you could have each cell have dayofweek (1 for sunday,2-monday etc) and date as attrributes of cells?

Comment: If the problem is just selecting and it's not some framework issue and adding script files is an option sizzle might be a better idea http://sizzlejs.com/

Comment: Thanks everyone for answers. It wont be that big, just few stuff saved and loaded from database, but i need the selection, to properly pick the cell to fill with the info from database. Thats why i decided to do it from scratch, that use existing script/library. i will read into jQuery :first and n-th. Also will read about "custom attributes" :o. Again, thanks!